# updating src attribute of img tag doesnt reflect the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am updating src attribute of image tag

```
<img src="assets/images/dummy.jpg" alt="" class="rounded-circle" id="logo-upload">
```

Above is the image tag with dummy src value

I am using file upload and after the file gets uploaded I am assigning the src of img tag with the file blob data

```
   this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (fileItem) => {
      this.filePreviewPath  = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl((window.URL.createObjectURL(fileItem._file)));
      let content:any= document.getElementById("logo-upload");
      content.src=this.filePreviewPath.changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity;
      console.log(content);
    }
```

when I check in the console I am getting like

```
<img _ngcontent-c5 alt class=​"rounded-circle" id=​"logo-upload" src=​"blob:​http:​/​/​localhost:​4200/​1b569f92-3873-4cd9-b456-e7652c92dd4a">​
```

But after that in the DOM it isnt getting reflected , it is the same with dummy image

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `blob:​http:​/​/​localhost:​4200/​1b569f92-3873-4cd9-b456-e7652c92dd4a` is not a valid value for this.

Comment: The value you are assigning to `src` is not a blob data

Comment: a valid blob in img.src shoud look something like this `src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg...."`

Comment: the blob conversion is not happening there. if you don't need additional functionality, you can use ngx-uploader